# Using User ID with Google Tag Manager / Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Hope somebody can help, I'm using GTM to push a userId variable over to google analytics, i can see the data in the chrome console / dataLayer but nothing is showing in the userID view on analytics. I'm using this code on my site at the top of the head:

```
<script>
   dataLayer = []
   dataLayer.push({ 'userId': <%= currentUser.number %> });
</script>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

And at the top of the body:

```
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

On GTM i have a Data Layer variable set up as userId (Data Layer version2) and in the tag configuration (fields to set) I have Field Name userId and value {{userId}}.

Over on analytics I have set up a UserId view and a Custom Dimension Name of userId (scope is User, Index is 1).

Am I missing something??

thanks.

Comment: Did you wait 24 hours?

Comment: No didn't realise there was a delay updating, will check again tomorrow - thanks.

Comment: Its working now - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code / setup I used above does work for showing userId within a userID view on analytics - as Ms.Easy said, you have to wait 24hrs for it to update.

Answer (score 0):

This might not work as you have declared `dataLayer.push` method above the GTM container.
You can only declare `dataLayer=[]`method above the GTM container. 
To send the user Id to GA, Use the below Code:

```
<script>
   dataLayer = [{ 'userId': <%= currentUser.number %> }];
</script>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

And at the top of the body:

```
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

Now set up the `dataLayer` variable and tag in GTM to capture the value and send to GA.

Hope this helps!